# Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ResizeObserver on Safari

Tags: reactjs, next.js, polyfills

My Next.js website is using a slider
https://github.com/nerdyman/react-compare-slider

It works great, but not on Safari, either Desktop or iPhone. here is my website
https://wordpress-website-headless-v2-afjayn5e2.vercel.app/

Close to the bottom of page I am using a comparison slider, this is causing the error.

I googled it, and it looks like many sliders have this issue on Safari, and the solution is to add a polyfill (https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill), which I did (I think) but it still doesn't work.. This is my full page code.

To summarize, it  works on Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari

```
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import ContainerFull from '../components/container-full'
import HomeStories from '../components/home-stories'
import MyCarousel from '../components/carousel'
import HeroPost from '../components/hero-post'
import Intro from '../components/intro'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { getHomePage, getHomeSlides, getAllPostsForLanding } from '../lib/api'
import { CMS_NAME } from '../lib/constants'
import Header from '../components/header'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'

import { ReactCompareSlider, ReactCompareSliderImage } from 'react-compare-slider';

export default function Page( {page, finearts, allTeases: { edges }} ) {

const allTeases = edges.slice(1)    
    




  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>{ page.seo.title }</title>
          <meta name="description" content={page.seo.metaDesc} />
        </Head>
       <Header />
        <ContainerFull>
         
      
        <Container fluid>
         <Row>
          <Col className="wrap-carousel">
                
                <MyCarousel finearts={finearts} />

          </Col>
         </Row>
        </Container>
        

      
      <Container className="pad-row-bottom">
            <Row>
                <Col xs={12}>
                    <h1>{ page.title }</h1>
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content }} />
                </Col>

                



            </Row>
        </Container>
      

    <Container fluid className="home-blog pad-row-bottom">
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col xs={12}>   <h2>Art Shows / News / Blog</h2></Col>
      
                {allTeases.length > 0 && <HomeStories posts={allTeases} />}
      
            </Row>
        </Container>
    </Container>            
                    
                
        <Container className="pad-row-bottom pad-row-top">
            <Row>
                <Col  xs={12} md={9}>
                    <h2>Commissioned Artwork</h2>
                        <p>
                            I can create a stunning pixel painting from any photograph provided. It could be yourself, family member, favourite celebrity, family pet, landcape, or just about anything.<br /><br />
                            All the artwork I create starts from a photo, which I use as reference to create an Op Art Painting. From close up, the paintings are close to abstract, but as you step away they come into focus.
                            <br /><br />
                            <strong>Call me today at  <a href="tel:416.450.5439">416.450.5439</a> to get a quote and get started on your personalized painting today.</strong>
      
                        </p>
                </Col>
      
                <Col  xs={12} md={3}>               
            
                        <ReactCompareSlider
  itemOne={<ReactCompareSliderImage src="https://res.cloudinary.com/djk8wzpz4/image/upload/v1611180870/MCA-pixel-portrait_jqm50p.jpg" srcSet="https://res.cloudinary.com/djk8wzpz4/image/upload/v1611180870/MCA-pixel-portrait_jqm50p.jpg" alt="Image one" />}
  itemTwo={<ReactCompareSliderImage src="https://res.cloudinary.com/djk8wzpz4/image/upload/v1611180870/MCA-original_wj8pjf.jpg" srcSet="https://res.cloudinary.com/djk8wzpz4/image/upload/v1611180870/MCA-original_wj8pjf.jpg" alt="Image two" />}
/>
                        
                </Col>              
                

            </Row>
        </Container>



            
    

        
      
          
        </ContainerFull>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}



export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false }) {
    
    
    
  const allTeases = await getAllPostsForLanding(preview)         
  console.log(allTeases)    
    
  const data = await getHomePage()
 
  const fineart = await getHomeSlides()
  console.log(fineart)  
  
  return {
    props: {
      page: data,
      finearts: fineart,
      allTeases, 
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello again, check out [react-app-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill), it may provide what you need (if the others you tried didn't), though I'm not sure if it plays nicely with SSR.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks !   no luck though, same error.. Do I need to do more than just import into my documents and install?

Comment: The react-app-polyfill need only be imported once in one of the root/app level components. Again though, I'm not familiar with how this works with SSR, but I'm sure many SSR'd apps have had to account for older browsers.

Comment: i found a pure css one to install instead, no headaches.. shoud i delete this?

Comment: Maybe post your solution/alternative as an answer to the question, but leave this open as other people might face the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got in touch with the developer and we worked it out (this one is much cooler than css one and works on mobile)

```
import { install } from "resize-observer";

// if you use next.js, use this

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
install();
}

// if you don't use next.js, this should work

install();
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer), a better solution is to use the [ponyfill](https://ponyfill.com/) if you're using ResizeObserver directly:

```
import { ResizeObserver } from 'resize-observer';

new ResizeObserver(
  () => console.log('resize observed!')
).observe(document.body);
```

But because it's an underlying library having the issue, best to use the polyfill. This snippet will only use the polyfill if it's missing (I'm assuming that Safari simply doesn't implement ResizeObserver rather than it existing but with a faulty implementation)

```
import { install } from 'resize-observer';

if (!window.ResizeObserver) install();

/** do react-compare-slider things */
```

Comment: The original post was using an older package "resize-observer-polyfill", which may have been the reason for the issues. Using the ponyfill from this new package "resize-observer" should still be the recommended solution.